# DDD dealing with Eventual consistency for multiple aggregates inside a bounded context with NoSQL

Tags: events, redis, event-handling, domain-driven-design, mediator

I am currently working on a DDD Geolocation application that has two separate aggregate roots inside one bounded context. Due to frequent coordinate updates I am using redis to persist my data which doesn't allow rollbacks.

1. My first aggregate root is a trip object containing driver (users), passengers (list of users), etc.
2. My second aggregate root is user position updates

When a coordinate update is sent I will generate and fire a "UpdateUserPostionEvent". As a side effect I will also generate and fire a "UpdateTripEvent" at a certain point, which will update coordinates of drivers/passengers.

My question is how can I deal with eventual consistency if I am firing my "UpdateLiveTripEvent" asynchronously. My UpdateLiveTripEventHandler has several points of failure and besides logging an error how can I deal with this inconsistency?

I am using a library called [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) and the INotificationHandler which is as far as I know is "Fire and Forget"

**Edit:** Ended up finding this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507822/eventual-consistency-across-aggregate-roots-in-the-same-bounded-context-using-a) that describes exactly what I need (saga/process manager) but unfortunately I am unable to find any kind of Saga implentation for handling events within the same BC. All examples I am seeing involve a sevice bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same or different Bounded Context; with or without Sagas; it does not matter.

Why a event handling fail? Domain rules or Infrastructure.

Domain rules:
A raised event handled by an aggregate (the event handler use the aggregate to apply the event) should NEVER fail by Domain Rules.

If the "target" aggregate has Domain Rules that reject the event your aggregate design is wrong. Commands/Operations can be rejected by Domain rules. Events can not be rejected (nor Undo) by Domain rules.

A event should be raised when all domain rules to this operation was checked by the "origin" aggregate. The "target" aggregate apply the event and maybe raises another event with some values calculated by the "target" aggregate (domain rules, but not for reject the event; events are unrejectable by domain rules; but to "continue" the consistency "chain" with good responsibility segregation). That is the reason why events should have sentences in past as names; because already happened.

Event simulation:

- Agg1: Hey buddies! User did this cool thing and everything seems to be OK. --> UserDidThisCoolThingEvent
- Agg2: Woha, that is awesome! I'm gonna put +3 in User points. --> UserReceivedSomePointsEvent
- Agg3: +3 points to this user? The user just reach 100 points. That is a lot! I'm gonna to convert this User into VIP User. --> UserTurnedIntoVIPEvent
- Agg4: A new VIP User? Let's notify it to the rest of the Users to create some envy ;)

Infrastructure:
Fix it and apply the event. ;) Even "by hand" if needed once your persistence engine, network and/or machine is up again.

Automatic retries for short time fails. ErrorQueues/Logs to not loose your events (and apply it later) in a long time outage.

Event sourcing also helps with this because you can always reapply the persisted events in the "target" aggegate without extra effort to keep events somewhere (i.e. event logs) because your domain persistence is also your event store.

Comment: I agree with this, but not in the case of cross-Aggregate changes. An Aggregate should be able to protect itself from being asked to attain an inconsistent state, *including* if the change was originally prompted by another Aggregate's event. IMO, inter-Aggregate cascading changes should go through intermediate Commands. You shouldn't subscribe to another Aggregate's events directly and treat them as if they were as safe to apply as your own.

Comment: @jlvaquero I should have mentioned that I was specifically referring to dealing with infrastructure failures. I am enforcing all invariants in my primary aggregate root to ensure no failures by domain rules. I do have logging and event sourcing in place but I am not sure how to leverage these to achieve eventual consistency in regards to long term infrastructure outages. I will try and do more research on this and look into error queues as I am unfamiliar with this concept.